# Changing data when using Reshape

Tags: python, arrays, reshape

I have next code:

```
sc_X = MinMaxScaler(feature_range= (0, 1))
X_train= sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
train_X = train_X.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, 131))
```

But as a result of the reshaping, a lot of my data has changed.

Data before reshaping:

> [[1.96645419e-02 2.10477532e-03 2.66453081e-02 ... 0.00000000e+00
> 1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
> [9.02427754e-02 1.48458198e-01 3.61012205e-01 ... 0.00000000e+00
> 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
> [1.15471005e-03 2.37881293e-04 2.35763396e-02 ... 0.00000000e+00
> 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
> ...
> [3.93841461e-03 1.65881338e-03 1.23813451e-01 ... 1.00000000e+00
> 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
> [1.71492089e-03 1.82042260e-03 3.10941230e-02 ... 0.00000000e+00
> 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
> [8.68466056e-03 9.95060108e-04 1.35129777e-02 ... 0.00000000e+00
> 1.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

And after:

> [[[-0.25588053 -0.29381111 -0.75765829 ... -0.44631536  2.23128064
> -0.44882273]]
>
> 0.53173065  1.35953179  1.3155043  ... -0.44631536 -0.44817312
> -0.44882273]]
>
> [[-0.46243926 -0.31490127 -0.7766867  ... -0.44631536 -0.44817312
> 2.22805116]]
>
> ...
>
> [[-0.43137477 -0.29884911 -0.15519028 ...  2.24056821 -0.44817312
> -0.44882273]]
>
> [[-0.45618764 -0.29702342 -0.73007447 ... -0.44631536 -0.44817312
> 2.22805116]]
>
> [[-0.37840948 -0.30634748 -0.83908219 ... -0.44631536  2.23128064
> -0.44882273]]]

Moreover, after the corresponding transformation of the output values, they did not change.
I'm new in Python, so I don't understand why this is happening.